# In order traversal for binary search tree without node pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, inorder

I have to code up a function for a lab in a binary search tree for in order traversal. My problem is I've been given an interface that I have to follow and in it the only parameter I can pass to the traversal function is another function of void return type:

```
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::inorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const
```

The visit function is basically a function that I would define for a specific use case for the tree, like say I want to print out the tree in ascending order in which case the function I would pass to the `inorderTraverse` function would be a print function. I can't figure out how to traverse the entire tree without having a node pointer as a parameter. I'm not asking for the entire code, just advice that can point me in the right direction! Here's the `BinarySearchTree.h`:

```
template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
class BinarySearchTree
{
private:
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* rootPtr;

   // Recursively deletes all nodes from the tree.
   void destroyTree(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr);

   // Recursively finds where the given node should be placed and
   // inserts it in a leaf at that point.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* insertInorder(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr,
                                   BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNode);

   // Returns a pointer to the node containing the given value,
   // or nullptr if not found.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* findNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr,
                              const KeyType& target) const;

public:
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Constructor and Destructor Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   BinarySearchTree();
   virtual ~BinarySearchTree();

   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Public Methods Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   bool add(const ItemType& newEntry);
   ItemType getEntry(const KeyType& aKey) const throw(NotFoundException);
   bool contains(const KeyType& aKey) const;

   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Public Traversals Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   void inorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;
}; // end BinarySearchTree

#include "BinarySearchTree.cpp"

#endif
```

Comment: you might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413705/c-binary-tree-traverse-and-function-pointer-parameter?rq=1

Comment: No, that's exactly my problem, I can't pass a node pointer to my function and that's why I can't figure out how to traverse recursively

Comment: Are you supposed to use recursion for it?

Comment: Not necessarily, it's just the post you referred me to was using recursion and I don't really know of any other way you could traverse a binary tree. Sorry, I'm not very experienced with this stuff!

Comment: `void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::inorderTraverse(...) const ` is **a method of the `BinarySearchTree`** -as such, you **do** have access to the root node of the tree inside the mehod. Your visitor won'y receive the node itself, but the visitor does *not* need to traverse the tree: it is the `inorderTraverse` that should do it.

Comment: Traverse a tree iteratively will be a pain. You will have to keep track of the nodes as you go down the tree if your `BinaryNode` does not have a way to access its parent. I never did implement it iteratively but a quick google search pointed to this implementation. That might help you get started : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion/

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Even for the `inorderTraverse` to traverse doesn't it still need a node pointer as an addtional parameter so it can keep track of what node it is on and go back recursively.

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly Asked my TA - am expected to use recursion though he didn't actually give any ideas on how to do it lol.

Comment: @pyro97 - "Even for the `inorderTraverse` to traverse doesn't it still need a node pointer as an addtional parameter" - Doh, use a helper function. See my answer. (and keep this in mind [as a lesson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Wheeler_(British_computer_scientist)):  "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection, except of course for the problem of too many indirections.")

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the `BinaryNode` has the methods

```
const BinaryNode* getLeft() const;
const BinaryNode* getRight() const;
const ItemType& getValue() const;
```

[Edited due to: "got told that we couldn't add anything extra to the class"]

You see, that method is `static` - it means it doesn't rely on any knowledge about the particular instant of your tree.

Because of this, it can be placed anywhere.

For example, just write it as a static function outside the class, inside your `"BinarySearchTree.cpp"` file.

**Another solution:** implement it inside the `inorderTraverse` method, as a [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) like in:

```
  // as a method of this class, you **do** have access to the root node
  void inorderTraverse(void visit(const ItemType&)) const {
    // this is a lambda function
    auto inOrderRecurse=(
      const BinaryNode<ItemType>* node, 
      void visit(const ItemType&)
    ) {
         if(node) {
           auto n=node->getLeft();
           if(n) {
              this->inOrderRecurse(n, visit);
           }
           visit(node->getValue());
           n=node->getRight();
           if(n) {
             this->inOrderRecurse(n, visit);
           }
        }
      }
    ;
    inOrderRecurse(this->rootPtr);
  }
```

**Yet another solution**: if you aren't allowed to use lambdas, you can still [declare a class/structure inside you method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876048/why-can-i-define-structures-and-classes-within-a-function-in-c). So, let's declare/use one in the very `inorderTraverse` method.

```
  // as a method of this class, you **do** have access to the root node
  void inorderTraverse(void visit(const ItemType&)) const {
    struct recurser {
      static void inOrderRecurse(
        const BinaryNode<ItemType>* node, 
        void visit(const ItemType&)
      ) {
       // etc...
      }
    };
    recurser::inOrderRecurse(this->rootPtr);
  }
```

---

[original answer]

As such, the `inorderTraverse` can be implemented as:

```
private:
  // "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection, 
  // except of course for the problem of too many indirections."
  // In the context, **this method** is another level of indirection
  static void inOrderRecurse(
      const BinaryNode<ItemType>* node, 
      void visit(const ItemType&)
  ) const {
   if(node) {
     auto n=node->getLeft();
     if(n) {
       this->inOrderRecurse(n, visit);
     }
     visit(node->getValue());
     n=node->getRight();
     if(n) {
       this->inOrderRecurse(n, visit);
     }
  }
public:

  // as a method of this class, you **do** have access to the root node
  void inorderTraverse(void visit(const ItemType&)) const {
    // note this `const` here  ---^ needed because of ^^^^ this one
    inOrderRecurse(this->rootPtr);
  }
```

Comment: I was told I can't add any private helper functions. Because that's what I was going to do originally but then our class got told that we couldn't add anything extra to the class, just define the methods that need definition.

Comment: @pyro97 Updated my answer with workarounds the requirement "no extra methods to the BinaryTree class"